# Recursively expanding short URLs in a big text - Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have collected text of about 2 * 10^5 rows, i have to expand the shortened URLs in the text. the problem is, that some expanded URLs redirect to again a shorten URL, which means that the original URL is 2 or more times shortened. how to handle that efficiently? because if i make a while loop, it is taking too much time.

The problem with the code below, is about 2*10^5 context switches from my MySQL DB. I extract the URL from each text and then expand it. This will make an http request, and then it has to be entered into my DB. it is taking too much time.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.URL;

public class urlExpander {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String shortenedUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oZTPGvG3s8&feature=youtu.be";
        String expandedURL = expandUrl(shortenedUrl);

        System.out.println(shortenedUrl + "-->" + expandedURL); 
    }

    public static String expandUrl(String shortenedUrl) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(shortenedUrl);    
        // open connection
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY); 

        // stop following browser redirect
        httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

        // extract location header containing the actual destination URL
        String expandedURL = httpURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        return expandedURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending of DB and your computer performance, you can use `MultiThreading` or various `Process`, you will be able to handle more than one request at once. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938193/2-threads-vs-2-processes-design-performance-isolation)

Comment: You could try to do the expanding asynchronously and wait for a couple of results to become available before writing them to the DB as a single batch.

Comment: If the expanded URL is a redirect, you should be able to catch that the redirects. Have a look at [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/).

Comment: Actually, you should look for a response code, too, instead of just the `Location` header. While the response code is of the [redirection class](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) (e.g. 301, 307, ...), you should follow the URL in the `Location` header. When the response code does not indicate a redirect (it is e.g. 200), then the potential `Location` header is meaningless.